# Can I use Elasticsearch https without cert and authentication

Tags: elasticsearch

I successfully setup HTTPS for Elasticsearch server. Now I can use curl like `curl -u elastic:111111 --cacerts "Path/to/my/cert" https://localhost:9200`. How can I setup to use curl without user authentication and cert?

Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: What happens if you simply set `xpack.security.enabled: false` in the configuration file?

Comment: I have to use HTTPS because it's required.

Comment: You can get rid of the `--cacerts` parameter if the certificate that protects the HTTPS communication between the ES server and your client is signed by an official root CA (i.e. not a self-signed certificate). But the user/password us mandatory as soon as you enable security. You can also replace `--cacerts` by `-k` in order to ignore the certificate validation, but that completely defeats the purpose of having HTTPS in the first place

Comment: `curl -u elastic https://localhost:9200 -k` does the trick, but when I want to connect to es using python (having connection string as the only possible method, without extra parameters), I can't - are there any workarounds?

Comment: @help-ukraine-now My workaround is that I use nginx as a https reverse proxy